# Why I can't select my first data in the picker view list?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

So I have a button in the view controller, and if I tap that label, it will show a pop up which is actually a picker view.

I will show the picker view pop up by using present modally, using the code below

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let popup = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "dataPickerPopup") as! DataPickerPopUpVC
popup.delegate = self
popup.selectionList = ["R16G","R22G"]
popup.titlePopup = "UNITS"
popup.startingData = availableUnits[0]
present(popup, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The picker view pop up will be look like this :
[image]

The code I use in the popupVC is like this :

```
import UIKit


protocol DataPickerPopupDelegate {
    func selectedValueFromPopUp (data: String)
}



class DataPickerPopUpVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var titlePopupLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var saveButton: UIButton!

    var selectionList : [String]!
    var pickedData = ""
    var startingData = ""
    var titlePopup = ""

    var delegate : DataPickerPopupDelegate?



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        pickerView.delegate = self
        setPickerViewStartingPosition()
        titlePopupLabel.text = titlePopup

    }


    @IBAction func saveButtonDidPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        // picked data will be sent to caller VC using protocol delegate pattern.

        delegate?.selectedValueFromPopUp(data: pickedData)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    @IBAction func closeReusablePopup(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }




}

extension DataPickerPopUpVC {
    // MARK: - Helper Methods

    func setPickerViewStartingPosition() {
        let index = selectionList.index(of: startingData)
        pickerView.selectRow(index ?? 0, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
    }
}



// MARK: - Picker View Delegate & Data Source
extension DataPickerPopUpVC : UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return selectionList.count
    }


    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        pickedData = selectionList[row]
    }


    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
        let pickerLabel = UILabel()
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
            pickerLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 40)
            pickerLabel.text = selectionList[row]
            pickerLabel.textAlignment = .center
        } else if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            pickerLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25)
            pickerLabel.text = selectionList[row]
            pickerLabel.textAlignment = .center
        }
        return pickerLabel
    }



}
```

After the user press 'Choose' button, it will send the selected units back to the caller VC using delegate pattern.

But I have something wrong in here. As you can see, the starting position of the picker view will always be "R16G". If I directly press the 'choose' button after the picker view pop up shows up, it seems it will always give me an empty string of selected data. It seems that the `didSelectRow` is not triggered.

But if I scroll down from "R16G" to "R22G" and then press 'choose' button, it will give string "R22G". I have no issue if i choose R22G.

And if I scroll down from "R16G" to "R22G" and then back again to  "R16G" and then press 'choose' button, it will give me the string "R16G", it works as I expected.

It seems the first list of the picker view doesn't give a string value back to me if I don't scroll down first.

Here is the .gif file of my problem : http://g.recordit.co/fRnvVJ2hi0.gif

How could I fix this? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: See my answer below.  For a UI point of view "Select" is probably a better verb than "Choose"

Comment: didSelectRow will be called when you change selection indicator , in gif we see that you didnt change selection indicator second time as @Paulw11 said you need pickerView.selectedRow method to get current row shown to user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the first value of array as selected and in didSelect you can update that variable with current value.

So in viewDidLoad() add these lines :

```
if !selectionList.isEmpty {
   pickedData = selectionList[0]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`didSelectRow` is only called when the user actually interacts with the picker to selects a new row.  It is not called when the picker is initially displayed, since the user did not select a row.

All you need to do is access the picker's current value in your button tap handler:

```
@IBAction func saveButtonDidPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    // picked data will be sent to caller VC using protocol delegate pattern.
    let pickedData = selectionList[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent:0)]
    delegate?.selectedValueFromPopUp(data: pickedData)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

You don't need the `pickedData` property or the `didSelect` delegate method.